# Minio NAS gateway security

Tags: authentication, authorization, minio

I am trying to understand what is the security setup for a Minio NAS gateway - documentation
[here](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-gateway-for-nas.html). Are all the [authorization/authentication options](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-sts-quickstart-guide.html) supported for a Minio server still valid? e.g. LDAP, OAUTH2/Openid, etc.?
In case of a distributed deployment (e.g. 3 nas gateways on the same NFS) will an update to a policy be propagated automatically to all the instances? (I assume it would, if it's stored on the NAS).
Apologies if I missed something in the documentation, any help appreciated.

Comment: Looks like the answer is scattered through the documentation. First, Minio in gateway mode requires etcd (quoted [here](https://docs.minio.io/docs/minio-multi-user-quickstart-guide.html) ). Once that is setup the user creation from the client starts working.

Comment: An etcd setup example can be found [here](https://github.com/minio/minio/blob/master/docs/sts/etcd.md), if the gateway is running in docker it requires  -e "MINIO_ETCD_ENDPOINTS=http://<address of etcd>:2379"